# Watson Assistant Change Format of Image Output to put Image to the left of the conversation

Tags: image, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

The Watson Assistant response type Image is great, in that you can post the textual response and post the image as multiple response types.  However the format is one above the other.  I'm looking for a way to post the image to the left or right of the text input/response box.  The use case is to display large pictures to the left or right of the text box.  One use case might be educational.  "Tell me about the Mona Lisa", might respond with a 70% of screen showing the art work and the text box talking about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about this [Image response type](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-dialog-responses#api-dialog-responses-image) in IBM Watson Assistant. It depends on the client how the image is displayed. I assume that you probably are using the [web chat](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat). You could look into [customizing the web chat](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-web-chat-config) to rearrange how images are shown.

Comment: Thanks, I went through the customizing pages and went to Sketch.com and found the layout I believe is what I want.  IBM Grid template/Grid influencers/
lg-1056px-16 column. The problem is I could not find or understand a sample on how to use this in the chat window config.  If anyone could show me where this would go I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Did you following the link to the theming help? https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#theming

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've been playing with this a bit, and I'm beginning to think I need to get a webhook involved and send my images to an iframe next to the chatbot and keep them in sync.  It would be cleaner if I could use text response AND image response, but I'm not seeing a clear path to that.

Comment: ok, I've changed my approach.  I've simply created an iframe outside of watson assistant on the web page and named it pictureWindow.  It does not work to simply put target="pictureWindow" in the image response, so I am thinking of creating a parent iframe and putting WA in a second child iframe.  Does that make sense or am I making this too complicated?